# What does it mean to take a field to the power of a group?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I read this in a paper about the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

for a field $K$, let $G $ be the set of subgroups of $Aut(K)$, and let $F$ be the set of subfields of $K$. define maps $\alpha:F \rightarrow G$ and $\beta:G \rightarrow F$ by:

$\alpha(E) = Aut(K/E)$

$\beta(H) = K^H $

What I don't understand is what $\beta$ means, of taking a field to the power of a group, and why it is the inverse of $\alpha$. Any explanation will be much appreciated.

Comment: The notation is shorthand for “the elements of $K$ that are fixed by every element of $H$”. That is, $K^H = \{ a\in K\mid \sigma(a)=a \text{ for all }\sigma\in H\}$.

Comment: P.S. That notation is standard for Galois Theory; it should be defined well ahead of any statement of the Fundamental Theorem. And if you are not familiar with it and the paper does not define it, then the paper assumes familiarity you do not have and you need to learn the basics before reading the paper.